# My java arrays overwrite existing elements

Tags: java, arrays

So I am relatively new to Java language but am trying to get better so I can add more skills to my resume. I am currently focusing on arrays and I am writing a program that I want to be able to use with a barcode scanner or keyboard in order to keep track of Cultural Enrichment credits (inspired by my school's need of one ). I thought it might be a neat starting program to wrap my head around array use but I am having a problem with the two arrays. They keep overwriting the new values entered. I have been googling and trying things but I am still not able to get them to work properly and would like to ask for help from more seasoned coders. I know my output method is rather lazy but it'll do for what I would like to see for the output format.

Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String []args)throws InputMismatchException
{
    Scanner user_input = new Scanner( System.in );

    int n = 0; 
    String Name;
    int CEU;
    String[] users = new String[5];
    String[] numbers = new String[6];
    Object end = null;
    Object print = null;

    System.out.print("Enter value for CEU: ");
    CEU = user_input.nextInt();

    while (n >= 0)
    {          

      /* Loop*/
      System.out.println("Scan ID or type  **end,print** ");
      numbers[n] = user_input.next();

      if ("end".equals(users[n] ))
      {
        System.out.print("Program terminated.");
        System.exit(0);
      }

      if ("print".equals(numbers[n]))         
      {

        System.out.print("CEUs: " + CEU);
        System.out.print(" ID#: " + numbers[0]);
        System.out.print(" Name: " + users[0]);

        System.out.print("\nCEUs: " + CEU);
        System.out.print(" ID#: " + numbers[1]);
        System.out.print(" Name: " + users[1]);

        System.out.print("\nCEUs: " + CEU);
        System.out.print(" ID#: " + numbers[2]);
        System.out.print(" Name: " + users[2]);

        System.out.print("\nCEUs: " + CEU);
        System.out.print(" ID#: " + numbers[3]);
        System.out.print(" Name: " + users[3]);

        System.out.print("\nCEUs: " + CEU);
        System.out.print(" ID#: " + numbers[4]);
        System.out.print(" Name: " + users[4]);

      }
      else 
      {

        System.out.print("Enter Name: ");
        users[n] = user_input.next();   

      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your loop you need to increment n as it is always 0. Use: n++; at the last line of code inside the while loop.

Comment: Good to know i could help you resolve your issue. Can you please upvote my answer? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

n isn't being incremented. Because n never changes, it will override the same part of the array each time the loop executes. Also, it seems like you may get a outofbounds error later, because i will keep increasing. Soon it will be greater than the max index of the numbers array, so it will return the error. You should try adding in some code that stops the error from happening.